# return all results from left tables along with right if something exists on left

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if the description is incorrect, I am not an expert in SQL...

I have the following query -

```
SELECT t1.ids, t1.name, t2.ids t3.ids FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 on t2.ids = t1.ids
LEFT JOIN tab3 t3 on t3.ids = t1.ids
```

The result of this query is return everything from `tab1` and if there is no match in `tab2` or `tab3` then it will display the fields as null...

```
| t1.ids | t1.name | t2.ids | t3.ids |
| 1      | n1      | null   | 1      |
| 2      | n2      | 2      | null   |
```

What I need is that if `tab1` doesn't match something in `tab2` or `tab3`, still return the `tab2` and `tab3` rows but with `tab1` fields null, so something like this:

```
| t1.ids | t1.name | t2.ids | t3.ids |
| 1      | n1      | null   | 1      |
| null   | null    | 1      | null   |
```

Any idea what is the most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Use a `FULL JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which is unfortunately not available in MySQL. You can use `UNION ALL` in this case:

```
SELECT t1.ids, t1.name, t2.ids t3.ids 
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 on t2.ids = t1.ids
LEFT JOIN tab3 t3 on t3.ids = t1.ids

UNION ALL

-- Get all t2 rows having no match in t1 
SELECT t1.ids, t1.name, t2.ids t3.ids 
FROM tab2 t2
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1 on t2.ids = t1.ids
LEFT JOIN tab3 t3 on t3.ids = t2.ids
WHERE t1.id IS NULL

UNION ALL

-- Get all rows in t3 having no match in t1 AND no match
-- in t2. Rows of t3 having no match in t1 and a match in t2
-- are returned by th previous query.
SELECT t1.ids, t1.name, t2.ids t3.ids 
FROM tab3 t3
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1 on t3.ids = t1.ids
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 on t2.ids = t3.ids
WHERE t1.id IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Giving it a go! Thanks a lot for the suggestion, will shout if it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a full outer join, which MySQL doesn't support. The easiest way to go about is, is to select all IDs first and then outer join all tables:

```
SELECT t1.ids, t1.name, t2.ids t3.ids 
FROM (SELECT ids FROM tab1 UNION SELECT ids FROM tab2 UNION SELECT ids FROM tab3) x
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1 on t1.ids = x.ids
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 on t2.ids = x.ids
LEFT JOIN tab3 t3 on t3.ids = x.ids;
```

Comment: looks much cleaner! although it took quite a while to execute with my current data set compared to having union all...

Comment: Yes, it's kind of brute force :-) The readability comes at a high price. A pity that MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.